# Unable to select an option from Spinner using Appium 1.6

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I am using Appium 1.6 to automate Android UI Tests.

In this image, I am unable to select any country (ex: Japan) from the spinner.

[image: screenshot]

This is the code I am using:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.akkipet.android:id/country_spinner__add_information")).click();    
driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("+ "new UiSelector().text(\"India\"));")).click()
```

What am I doing wrong? After clicking on the spinner, though I'm not able to read the country values, I can read other fields like First Name, Last Name etc.

For now, I am using the tap functionality to tap at the specific coordinates to choose the required option. But this will make it device specific. Further, since the options list varies depending on the environment, I will have to give a different set of coordinates for each environment.

Code for Tap:

```
touchAction.tap (200, 850).perform();
```

Could anyone suggest a better workaround?

Comment: post your appium logs

Comment: Which logs exactly do you need?

Comment: As i mention appium logs, means appium server full logs

Comment: Sorry for the delay

Here are my Appium Logs:

https://gist.github.com/AshrayViswanath/4316273924c1b8d0f348e0cf85215f74

Comment: Is this a hybrid app ?

Comment: It is a native app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It worked for me.
`driver.findElement(By.id("com.akkipet.android:id/country_spinner__add_information")).click();

driver.findElement(By.name("India")).click();`

Comment: I tried using this, but in appium 1.6.5 but it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`By.Name` has been deprecated. Try using `findElementByAndroidUIAutomator`.

Eg:

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text("India")").click();
```